# incorrect SQL where clause generated from HQL since hibernate 6 using test on left join on where clause

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql, jpql

Since I migrate to Hibernate 6 (5.4.30.Final to 6.2.0.Final), some of my queries is not translated correctly.

Here is a minimal reproduction project based on [this tutorial](https://www.javaguides.net/2023/03/hibernate-6-example-tutorial.html):

Entities (getters/setters are omitted):

```
@Entity
public class Author {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String name;
}

@Entity
public class PublishingHouse {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String name;
}
```

A book has a foreign key to Author and Publishing house:

```
@Entity
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String title;
    
    @ManyToOne
    private Author author;
    
    @ManyToOne
    private PublishingHouse publishingHouse;
}
```

My Main method add entites, then try to find all books which have either "Stephen king" as author or "Simon & Schuster" as a publishing house:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Transaction transaction = null;
        PublishingHouse phSimonSchuster = null;
        Author stephenKing = null;
        
        try (Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()) {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            
            
            /**
             *  Add Publishing houses
             */
        
            phSimonSchuster = new PublishingHouse();
            phSimonSchuster.setName("Simon & Schuster");
            session.persist(phSimonSchuster);
            
            var phHarperCollins = new PublishingHouse();
            phHarperCollins.setName("HarperCollins");
            session.persist(phHarperCollins);
            
            
            /**
             * Add Authors
             */
            
            stephenKing = new Author();
            stephenKing.setName("Stephen King");
            session.persist(stephenKing);
            
            var hpLovecraft = new Author();
            hpLovecraft.setName("Howard Phillips Lovecraft");
            session.persist(hpLovecraft);
            
            
            /**
             * Add Books
             */
            
            var bShining = new Book();
            bShining.setTitle("Shining");
            bShining.setAuthor(stephenKing);
            bShining.setPublishingHouse(phSimonSchuster);
            session.persist(bShining);
            
            var bColorOutOfSpace = new Book();
            bColorOutOfSpace.setTitle("The Colour Out of Space");
            bColorOutOfSpace.setAuthor(hpLovecraft);
            bColorOutOfSpace.setPublishingHouse(phHarperCollins);
            session.persist(bColorOutOfSpace);
        
            transaction.commit();
        }
        
        try (Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()) {
            
            var hql = "SELECT book "
                    + "FROM Book book "
                    + "   LEFT JOIN book.author author "
                    + "        WITH author.id = :stephenKingId "
                    + "   LEFT JOIN book.publishingHouse publishingHouse "
                    + "        WITH publishingHouse.id = :simonSchusterId "
                    + "WHERE author IS NOT NULL OR publishingHouse IS NOT NULL ";
            
            List<Book> books = session.createQuery(hql, Book.class)
                    .setParameter("stephenKingId", stephenKing.getId())
                    .setParameter("simonSchusterId", phSimonSchuster.getId())
                    .list();
            books.forEach(b -> {
                System.out.println("Book found: " + b.getTitle());
            });
        }
        
    }
```

Output of my main method is:

> Book found: Shining
> Book found: The Colour Out of Space

But "The Colour Out of Space" is not written by Stephen king and is not publishing by "Simon & Schuster", as you can see when I insert data, so this book shouldn't be get by this query.

The problem is that this hql:

```
SELECT book
FROM Book book
   LEFT JOIN book.author author
        WITH author.id = :stephenKingId
   LEFT JOIN book.publishingHouse publishingHouse
        WITH publishingHouse.id = :simonSchusterId
WHERE author IS NOT NULL OR publishingHouse IS NOT NULL
```

Is translated wrong:

```
SELECT b1_0.id,
       b1_0.author_id,
       b1_0.publishinghouse_id,
       b1_0.title
FROM   book b1_0
       LEFT JOIN author a1_0
              ON a1_0.id = b1_0.author_id
             AND b1_0.author_id = ?
       LEFT JOIN publishinghouse p1_0
              ON p1_0.id = b1_0.publishinghouse_id
             AND b1_0.publishinghouse_id = ?
WHERE  b1_0.author_id IS NOT NULL
   OR b1_0.publishinghouse_id IS NOT NULL
```

Why it's wrong ? Because the WHERE condition is testing if `author_id` and `publishinghouse_id` is not null, not on LEFT JOIN but on `Book` entity. And of course, every books have an `author_id` and `publishinghouse_id`  so every books are retrieved in the query. But in HQL query, test is on LEFT JOIN.
There is another problem: in HQL, the WITH clause is testing Id of LEFT JOIN aliases, so:

```
FROM book book
LEFT JOIN book.author author
     WITH author.id = :stephenKingId
```

should be:

```
FROM book b1_0
LEFT JOIN author a1_0
       ON a1_0.id = b1_0.author_id
      AND a1_0.id = ?
```

**And not**:

```
FROM book b1_0
LEFT JOIN author a1_0
       ON a1_0.id = b1_0.author_id
      AND b1_0.author_id = ?
```

Finally, The right query should be:

```
SELECT b1_0.id,
       b1_0.author_id,
       b1_0.publishinghouse_id,
       b1_0.title
FROM   book b1_0
       LEFT JOIN author a1_0
              ON a1_0.id = b1_0.author_id
             AND a1_0.id = ?
       LEFT JOIN publishinghouse p1_0
              ON p1_0.id = b1_0.publishinghouse_id
             AND p1_0.id = ?
WHERE a1_0.id IS NOT NULL OR p1_0.id IS NOT NULL
```

This query find only books which have either "Stephen king" as author or "Simon & Schuster" as a publishing house

I don't have this problem with hibernate version < 6.0

Comment: The generated SQL looks fine to me.  The `mme.entityA_id` should only be non null if there is some value in the associated `EntityA` table.

Comment: It's wrong because EntityA and EntityB selection is restrained by `entityA.id IN (:entitiesAIds)` so, the HQL query should get only MyMainEntity which have either EntityA association WITH specific ID's or EntityB association WITH specific ID's. 
Currently, request return all MyMainEntity which have EntityA  or EntityB  association no matter specifics ID's mentionned in IN clause

Comment: You should add the raw query you want, and maybe some sample data.  I reckon that `WITH` is not often used or needed in HQL queries.

Comment: I'm *really* struggling to understand WTH you are trying to do here with this query, and why you think the generated SQL is "incorrect". I'm inclined toward thinking you're doing something non-sensible, but if that's not the case, you need to add a lot more information to explain why you need such a strange-looking query.

Comment: I do not doing something non-sensible, I juste want to get MyMainEntity lines which have association EntityA or EntityB with specifics Ids. I will post more details and a minimal reproduction project, simplier than this query.

Comment: @GavinKing I completely rewrote my post to make it better understandable

Answer (score 2):

I suggest a simpler query:

```
SELECT b.id, b.author.id, b.publishingHouse.id, b.title 
FROM Book b 
LEFT JOIN b.author a 
LEFT JOIN b.publishingHouse p 
WHERE a.id = :authorId OR p.id = :publishingHouseId
```

You could use WITH:

```
SELECT b.id, b.author.id, b.publishingHouse.id, b.title
FROM Book b
LEFT JOIN b.author a WITH a.id = :authorId
LEFT JOIN b.publishingHouse p WITH p.id = :publishingHouseId
WHERE a.id IS NOT NULL OR p.id IS NOT NULL
```

or, explicitly specify the join conditions:

```
SELECT b.id, b.author.id, b.publishingHouse.id, b.title 
FROM Book b 
LEFT JOIN b.author a ON a.id = :authorId 
LEFT JOIN b.publishingHouse p ON p.id = :publishingHouseId 
WHERE a.id IS NOT NULL OR p.id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I just try your first simplier query and it is working, thanks. But the fact is I have to check hundred of query and changes it, and I would like to avoid it. Your second and third query is like what I am doing now, so it doesn't work as expected because generated SQL query do not match HQL, test of NULL is on wrong table, and test of `a.id` and `p.id` too

Comment: Interesting that the generated sql doesn't match...

Comment: Paul, the generated SQL is different in the first case because Hibernate 6 is smart enough to figure out that the two `left join`s are superfluous and it optimizes them away. But for the other two (more complicated) queries it's not quite that smart.

Comment: The first query worked as expected and the left joins aren't superfluous as both are necessary to allow unmatched rows. I am surprised that the more explicit syntax used in the latter 2 queries is ignored.

Comment: They *are* superfluous. The whole query is equivalent to `FROM Book book
WHERE book.author.id = :stephenKingId OR book.publishingHouse.id = :simonSchusterId`

Comment: Ah, now I see your point. True. Obvious once pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

I mean, if I'm understanding this correctly, you're trying to use the `is not null` conditions to emulate the effect of two regular inner joins.

Why not just write the query using inner joins in the first place?

Either:

```
SELECT book
FROM Book book
   JOIN book.author author
       WITH author.id = :stephenKingId
   JOIN book.publishingHouse publishingHouse
       WITH publishingHouse.id = :simonSchusterId
```

or even just:

```
SELECT book
FROM Book book
   JOIN book.author author
   JOIN book.publishingHouse publishingHouse
WHERE author.id = :stephenKingId 
  AND publishingHouse.id = :simonSchusterId
```

I mean, I'm just not sure why why it would occur to use outer joins here.

#### UPDATE

I missed that it was an `or` in the restriction. In that case, something like:

```
SELECT book
FROM Book book
   JOIN book.author author
WHERE author.id = :stephenKingId 
UNION
SELECT book
FROM Book book
   JOIN book.publishingHouse publishingHouse
WHERE publishingHouse.id = :simonSchusterId
```

or something like that.

#### UPDATE 2

Actually I've been completely dense! This query avoids the joins completely:

```
FROM Book book
WHERE book.author.id = :stephenKingId 
   OR book.publishingHouse.id = :simonSchusterId
```

(I *felt like* something stunk about the original query, but just failed to put my finger on it at first.)

Comment: using inner joins will only return where both conditions are matched, but there can be an author that uses more than one publisher, or more then one author from the publisher - and these are required in the result as I understand it

Comment: Oh I see, good point, I missed that it was `or` in the `where` condition.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I try and it is working with UNION. However, there is hundred of HQL queries in my app so I would like to avoid check all queries to fix it. Queries I write is correct with hibernate < 6 so I don't undertand because now it doesn't working anymore

Comment: Hibernate 6 is a whole new major version, with a _completely_ rewritten and _much_ improved implementation of HQL. Some differences in behavior are absolutely to be expected, and it's not at all clear that this change in behavior is "wrong". I will of course think it through it some more, and talk to the team, so we can decide what we think the behavior _should_ be. But we also don't apologize for making breaking improvements in major versions. That's the meaning of a major version increment.

Comment: Actually don't use `union`. See my second update.

Comment: Also, I've opened this issue: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16505

Comment: Thanks you very much @GavinKing for opening issue on hibernate jira. I try with your query 'UPDATE  2' and It works: SQL generated is correct for this usecase! But if I use @OneToMany association (I mean: `Book 1-> n Author` and `Book 1 -> n  PublishingHouse`), two LEFT JOIN associations is mandatory (caused by `@OneToMany` instead of `@ManyToOne`) - I know this example is totally absurd for this usecase but it's just for explanation

Comment: Well, OK, but `@OneToMany` is just completely different, and the whole problem doesn't arise. The query `select a from Author a left join a.books b where b is not null` results in `where b1_0.id is not null` which is already what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Before hibernate 6:
select * from A left join B on A.deviceId = B.id where B.id is not null

=> The SQL is correctly generated.

After upgrading to hibernate 6. The generated SQL is wrong:
select * from A left join B on A.deviceId = B.id where A.deviceId is not null

=> We have to introduce some work around to solve this issue.
=> I think it is a bug in hibernate 6